# Where to put custom logic not related to any model in a REST api in node?

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

Where do we put the logic not related to any one model say for example if we have to find matches similar to tinder matches based on his/her preferences and location? If possible answer this question in the context Strongloops loopback framework.

Comment: im guessing as a bootscript but want to understand the accepted convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use models too. In loopback there are two model types : persisted/not-persisted. In loopback model is  flexible and not limited to data models.

For your need you can create a model inherited `Model` and put all your tinder login there. Then use it in other places too.

```
//tinder.json
  "name": "Tinder",
  "plural": "ti",
  "base": "Model",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": true,
```

Boot scripts are just for running some code in starting phase. For example you can check for some roles existing in db or not.

Comment: maybe i didnt explain correctly, but i was talking about the matching logic to find matches. So in a normal express app I would just create an endpoint whose controller would run a db query to find users based on current user's preferences like age or distance. But to implement this via a model seems counter-intuitive, unless I misunderstood. I was thinking more like a new boot script that would do the logic and we can then expose it via the api. Please pardon my ignorance and comment if i am making some sense